# How to count in jquery, adding and subtracting numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I have this little script. I need to add and remove elements at my shop basket. So i have a simple counter, but it's not work corectly. When i'm parsing actual number and add another one everythin is fine, but - i can't add another one, and when i'm subctracting it brings me an zero. Can you help me? My code and some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5vuJQ/:

```
$(function(products_counter){
    var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
    var n_place = $('.lce_number');
    $('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
        n_place.empty().append(n + 1);
    });
    $('.lce_remove').live('click', function(){
        n_place.empty().append(n - 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pick up the number from `.lce_number` on each click. Note, `live()` method was deprecated, you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
var n_place = $('.lce_number');
$('.line_count_elements').on('click', '.lce_add', function() {
    var n = parseInt(n_place.text(), 10);
    n_place.html(n + 1);
});
$('.line_count_elements').on('click', '.lce_remove', function() {
    var n = parseInt(n_place.text(), 10);
    n_place.html(Math.max(0, n - 1));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5vuJQ/7/

Comment: If you use delegation, you should unbind too using .off('click') i think

Comment: @roasted Why do you think so?

Comment: If elements are added dynamically, .on() as delegate will set multi-binds, no?

Comment: what if ihave and zero? i don't need -1 element :)

Comment: thx man, it works perfect, i'v change it a little bit (http://jsfiddle.net/5vuJQ/9/) but much thx for help, u rox :)

Comment: @roasted Though I don't know what you mean under *multi-binds*, delegated events in `on` work a bit differently. You may read about it here: http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/12/switch-on-with-jquerys-new-event-methods/.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski You're welcome! ;) But I truly recommend you not to use `live()`.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski Because it is deprecated and soon will not be supported. Moreover, `live()` method is slower than *"tuned"* `on()`.

Comment: ohhh yeah, totally forgot about that - indeed, solution with .on() will be much better, thx again for your interest

Answer (score 1):

You could try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/5vuJQ/8/

```
$(function(products_counter){
        var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
        var n_place = $('.lce_number');
        $('.lce_add').on('click', function(){
            n_place.empty().append(++n);
        });
        $('.lce_remove').on('click', function(){
            if(n>0)
              n_place.empty().append(--n);
        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(products_counter){
    var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
    $('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
       $('.lce_number').text(parseInt($('.lce_number').text())+1);
    });
    $('.lce_remove').live('click', function(){
         $('.lce_number').text(parseInt($('.lce_number').text())-1);
    });
});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Zzbet/

Comment: so, what if ihave and zero? i don't need -1 element :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(products_counter){
    var n_place = $('.lce_number');
    $('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
        var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
        n_place.empty().append(n + 1);
    });
    $('.lce_remove').live('click', function(){
        var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text())
        n_place.empty().append(n - 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(products_counter){      
    var n_place = $('.lce_number');
    $('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
        var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
        n_place.empty().append(n + 1);
    });
    $('.lce_remove').live('click', function(){
        var n = parseInt($('.lce_number').text());
        n_place.empty().append(n - 1);
    });
});
```

You need to get the value of `n` after each click!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
        n_place.empty().append(n + 1);
    });
```

Above lines in your code are **not** modifying the value of '**n**'

**To start with -** n = 1 
**On 1st click** - append(n + 1)  --> 1+ 1  ---> results in 2 being shown
***n*** is still 1 
**On 2nd click** - append(n + 1)  --> 1+ 1 --> again results in 2 
**n** is still 1, hence this repeats

You need to modify the value of '**n**' **before** calling append()

```
 $('.lce_add').live('click', function(){
        n = n + 1;
        n_place.empty().append(n);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tbqX/1/